# How to write an application once for Android and Iphone?

Tags: android, iphone, cordova

How can I make an Android && iPhone (iOS) && Symbian application write only 1 time ?
I have seen some tools like phonegap, appcelerator but I saw someting that if I want to make iPhone apps I need an Mac :|.. I have Windows 7 x64 bit.

If is there a solution for me, please tell me. I preffer to write in Web Technologies (such as PHP/HTML/CSS/Javascript), but it's ok everything.

I need an application whitch it's able to do:
- GPS/Internet localization
- integrate Google Maps
- chat
- Facebook/Google/(Twitter) login
- to look beautiful

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phonegap gives online tools to package apps for different OSs (like the ones you mention). See:

[PhoneGap™ Build](https://build.phonegap.com/)

However, it's free only for one app. If you like using Javascript, Phonegap (or it's open source equilavent Apache Cordova) is a good solution.

Comment: ok.. If I want to install phonegap, in the CMD if I write npm install -g phonegap  => i get errors.. How to fix ?

Comment: What kind of errors? I suppose you have already installed NodeJS.

Comment: yes.. i instaled nodejs. can we speak on skype or ym? please PM me

Comment: these are my problems: http://s22.postimg.org/5qvagrtv5/Untitled.png

Comment: See the errors that come up during install. There should also be a npm-debug.log in your user directory. Perhaps you need to install something else also.EDIT: From the errors you posted it says you need to install git

Comment: can you give me the link of git to download...?

Comment: thank you! i ownloaded git and now it downloads. but now i have other problems.. i will make a screen recording